# How to declare a global variable in matlab that points to java class

Tags: java, matlab

I have a Matlab **level-2 S-Function `ABC`** which has a variable `Z` pointing to a  `javaclassABC`

```
Z= javaclassABC();
```

I want to use the same `Z` in another **level-2 S-Function `XYZ`**.

How do I declare `Z`? with global?

If anyone can provide a simple example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is the meaning of _level-2 S_? Function defined within another function? Do you mean Java Class or Java Class Instance (Object)? Because you ask about Java Classes, which are already singletons, so no need for a global variable.

Comment: I mean java class. Level-2 S-function is one type of function and I use it insde simulink. I created two blocks S-function and in each one I declared two script functions. In function A.m I declared a variable , for instance , B = javaclassABC ( the file classpath.txt was modified to load dynamics class). In function C , I want to use the same variable B that points to class javaClassABC. Hope that can explain more

Comment: Why you don't state in both functions `javaObjectEDT('javaclassABC')
`? Java Classes are already global. You can see what classes are loaded with `[M,X,J] = inmem; disp(J)`.